# Why isn't my WiX installer creating directories and copying my file

Tags: wix

I am creating a Wix installer. I want to install my program and another file into the default programs folder, This is working fine.

I also want to put a file in folder "C:\Checkmark\Data", if this folder doesn't exist I want WiX to create it. This folder is not being created, and nothing is happening with the file.

My WiX file:

```
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Checkmark" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductData"/>
    </Feature>
<!--<UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal"/>-->
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Checkmark" />
        </Directory>
  <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
    <Directory Id="CHECKMARKFOLDER" Name="Checkmark">
      <Directory Id="DATAFOLDER" Name="Data" />
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
<ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <Component Id="cmp_Checkmark.exe" Guid="B67B6527-C685-417F-A749-C8B908DF6AEF">
    <File Id="fil_Checkmark.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\WPF test Projects\Checkmark\Checkmark\bin\Release\Checkmark.exe"/>
  </Component>
  <!--Overwrites file no matter what-->
  <Component Id="cmp_TestDoc.txt" Guid="D2147C11-E2A4-4B78-8195-63788F88B012">
    <File Id="fil_TestDoc.txt" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\WPF test Projects\Checkmark\Checkmark\TestDoc.txt"/>
  </Component>      
    </ComponentGroup>
<ComponentGroup Id="ProductData" Directory="DATAFOLDER">
  <!--Does not overwrite File if it exists-->
  <Component Id="cmp_KeepDoc.txt" NeverOverwrite="yes" Guid="02B29D8B-813C-4782-A6EC-EB614B218D84">
    <File Id="fil_KeepDoc.txt" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\WPF test Projects\Checkmark\Checkmark\KeepDoc.txt"/>
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Can someone tell me why this folder isn't being created and my file not going in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put data in C:\CheckMark\Data

You could use following directory structure:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Checkmark" />
    </Directory>        
    <Directory Id="CHECKMARKFOLDER" Name="Checkmark">
        <Directory Id="DATAFOLDER" Name="Data" />
    </Directory>        
</Directory>
```

But TARGETDIR resolves to drive with maximum freespace.
So If you seriously want to deploy in C Drive,
you should update value of TARGETDIR to "C:\" explicitly.

Also CommonAppDataFolder resolves to another directory depending on host os.
On Windows Vista/7 it resolves to C:\ProgramData.

You should check this link for more info.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367992(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion worked. I checked out the link and think I understand how the keyword folder association works. So far I've found the documentation for Wix a little lacking.